# SharePoint 2013: Edit Renditions button missing

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I've seen tutorials that claim there is an "Edit Renditions" button, and/or a Design tab on the ribbon with the option to edit renditions. However, I do not see either of these options. Please see below. The first image is what I see. (Note: Ribbon is not shown, but there is no Design tab, only Browse, Files, and Library tabs.) The second and third images are what I should be seeing, according to [this](https://blog.mastykarz.nl/image-renditions-sharepoint-2013/) and [this](https://hangconsult.com/2017/02/01/sharepoint-101-image-column-in-sharepoint-list-view/).

[image: What I see on my end]

[image: Edit Renditions button]

[image: Design tab with Edit Renditions button]

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you meet the prerequisites to use this feature.

Prerequisites include:

1. Enable publishing features at the site collection level and site level.
2. [Enable BLOB cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/SharePoint/administration/cache-settings-configuration-for-a-web-application?redirectedfrom=MSDN) for your web application.
3. Use an asset library to store your images.

Please check the above, make sure you have configured them all. After that, when you click an image from the asset library, it will show as the following:
[image]

If you edit an image from an asset library on a page, the below will be displayed:
[image]
More information about image renditions, you can refer to [the article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/sharepoint-design-manager-image-renditions#prerequisites-for-managing-image-renditions).